# Combinatorics Inequality Induction Problem

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, induction

I am having trouble with an induction problem in my number theory class.

The problem asks me to prove that: 
$$2\cdot{3^n}^{-1}\le{2n \choose n}$$ for $n\ge0$, where:

$${2n \choose n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

I have done the base case of $n=1$ which shows that $2\le2$ which is indeed true. I'm having trouble from going from the $k$-substitution step to $k+1$

Comment: Take $n=2$ to be your base case & show that $\frac{2k+1}{k+1} \geq \frac{3}{2}$ ...

Comment: I understand that the first inductive step is to substitute n with k, but how can I make that statement involving k into a k+1 statement using algebraic manipulation?

Comment: ... $ \binom{2k+2}{k+1}= \frac{2k+2}{k+1} \frac{2k+1}{k+1} \binom{2k}{k}$ ...

Comment: What about the other side of the inequality? $$2\cdot{3^k}^{-1}\le{2k \choose k}$$ is the first inductive step. Even i multiply by what you say what happens to the other side with 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\dbinom{2n}{n}\ge2\cdot3^{n-1}$. We have to prove:

$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}\ge2\cdot3^n$$

$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(n+1)(n+1)}\cdot\binom{2n}{n}$$

$$\ge\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(n+1)(n+1)}\cdot2\cdot3^{n-1}$$

$$=\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3^{n-1}$$

$$=\frac{n+1+n}{n+1}\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3^{n-1}$$

$$=\left(1+\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3^{n-1}$$

If we can prove $\dfrac{n}{n+1}\ge\dfrac12$, we will have:

$$\ge2\cdot3^n$$

which proves the case for $n+1$.

And we have:

$$2n\ge n+1\;\;\forall n\ge1$$

Comment: Thank you; however, the problem gives a bound on n $\ge$0. You're solution shows this for n$\ge$1. How should I show that 0 works as well?

Comment: do it separately: $\frac23\lt1$